# How to make a list of random combinations of index?

Tags: python, list, combinations

Here I have a list that has about 6000 elements. (1~6000)

And I'm trying to make a combinations of its index, but 6000 combination 2 nearly has 20 million number of cases.

So, beyond calculating all possible 20 million combination cases, I want to randomly make combination that has less cases like 5 or 3 million cases.

```
def binary_indexing(dataframe):
    # Dataframe has almost 6000 rows
    numList = list(range(len(dataframe)))
    
    # Calculating below code takes too much time since it has immense number of cases.
    indexList = list(combinations(numList , 2))
```

I've tried to use `import random` and `randomList = random.sample(indexList, len(indexList))`.

But since anyway it has to calculate all possible combinations, it didn't work well.

Comment: you should try `itertools`

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
"Didn't work well" is not a problem specification.  What are you expecting for "work well" in this case?

Comment: Are you just trying to pick out two random rows? Then what's wrong with `randomList = random.sample(indexList, 2)`?

Comment: If the data contains `length` elements and you want `num_cases` random indices, you could use `random.sample(range(length*(length-1)), num_cases)`

Comment: By using list, you are forcing the combinations generator to generate all the values.  You should just unravel the generator the number of entries you need.  This might work, though I don't have a lot of generator experience: `indexList = [next(combinations(numList,2)) for _ in range(50000)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3,000,000 combos of two numbers, you can pair every of the 6000 numbers with a random sample of 500 numbers as follows:

```
import random
lst = [i for i in range(6000)]
sample = random.sample(lst, 500)
combos = [(i, j) for i in lst for j in sample]

print(f'First 10 combos: {combos[:10]}')
#First 10 combos: [(0, 842), (0, 4387), (0, 3198), (0, 1907), (0, 5332), (0, 4923), (0, 5802), (0, 1346), (0, 197), (0, 2885)]

print(len(combos))
#3000000
```